# How to merge results from functions executed using foreach in pyspark?

Tags: foreach, pyspark

I am trying to merge the output values of a function executed through `foreach` in PySpark.
Here is the pseudo-code:

```
files_rdd = sc.parallelize(files)
files_rdd.foreach(lambda x: training_cart(x, min_leaf=10, pruning=True))

get each CART model and dump it as pickle
Build a list/dictionary where each trained CART is inserted
```

where,

```
def training_cart(file, min_leaf=10, pruning=True):
  read out file
  model = train classification tree
  return model
```

The idea is then to take each CART model and insert it into a list/dictionary to be used after the training phase as well as to dump them as independent pickle files to be used later on. Can anyone give me a hand how to do it?